# Parameterizing Cloudfront custom_error_response elements in a module

Tags: terraform

`aws_cloudfront_distribution` can contain multiple `custom_error_response` blocks. I'm creating a module that contains a cloudfront distribution and I'd like the user of the module to specify error handling rules. At the very least a boolean flag with a standard redirect. Is this possible? How does one achieve that?

Comment: Terraform allows for conditional stuff by using the ternary syntax around the `count` meta parameter that you can use on resources and data sources. Unfortunately this isn't available for "sub resources" such as a stanza/block in a resource. If you have a wildly different Cloudfront distribution for each use case then it's not going to be easy/useful to wrap it in a module really without a lot of copy pasting of the  resource inside the module and then conditionally creating each one.

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR. They're all the same with the exception of error page handling. :-/